# I set ajax async: false but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to get json form other domain, my code is as below:

```
var token = '';
function getData(){
  console.log("get data suc");
  for (var i=0; i < urls.length; i++){
     var code = 'http://example.com/api/'+ urls[i];
     $.ajax({
       async: false,
       url: code,
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success: function(data) { showData(data); },
       error: function() { console.log('ajax Failed!'); },
       beforeSend: setHeader,
     });
  }
}
function showData(data){
  $("<tr></tr>").append("<td>" + data + "</td>")
    .appendTo("#results");
  console.log(data);
}
function setHeader(xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);
}
```

This result should be display as order the key I gave from array urls.
ex: urls = [1,2,3,4]→should get [one,two,three,four]
but I always get the wrong order!(ex: [two,one,three,four] or [three,four,two,one])
What happened?
Is that "async: false" didn't work? And why?

Comment: even if your `async: false` worked, it would have been a bad idea.

Comment: Understand [how JSONP works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and realize that it will never by synchronous.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `jsonp` request which does not support `async:false`.

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active.

So try

```
function getData() {
    function request(urls, i) {
        var code = 'http://example.com/api/' + urls[i];
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: code,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                showData(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('ajax Failed!');
            },
            beforeSend: setHeader,
        }).always(function () {
            i++;
            if (i < urls.length) {
                request(urls, i);
            }
        });
    }
    console.log("get data suc");
    request(urls, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, `async: false` does not work for JSONP requests.

If you really need synchronous behavior, you'd need a sequence of requests where the success callback from the first initiates the second, and so on. Really, though, it would be preferable if you simply handled the responses in the order that they appear.

For instance, you could pass the index variable:

```
function getCallback(i) {
   return function(data) {
      showData(data, i);
   };
};

...

$.ajax({
   ...
   success: getCallback(i)
 });

...

function showData(data, i){
   // use 'i' here to determine where to insert the record
}
```